# How to fix the error "missing field name in " for the test using testing library and graphql?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

i want to remove this warning "missing field" when running tests.

i am using testing library with jest for react using graphql.

i have my test like below,

```
test('add button disabled', async () => {
    const count_variable: Count = {
        first: 0,
        second: 2,
    };
    const { getByTestId } = utils.render(
        <SomeComponent />,
            [
                utils.gqlMock(GET_COUNT, count_variable),
            ]
    );
    //some logic to test
});
```

the query GET_COUNT looks like below,

```
query GetCount {
    getCount {
        first
        second
    }
 }
`;
```

Type Count is as below

```
export interface Count {
    first: number;
    second: number;
}
```

Could some help me fix the warning "missing field Count in 0". Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't  const count_variable: count be  const count_variable: Count?

Comment: yes that was a typo i shall edit it